# Pie chart can be shown in Title Band in jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

There is requirement that I have to show pie chart on the Title Band of the jasper report. I have tried so much but whenever I add the pie chart in the title band It does not shoe me the chart but when I add the chart in the summary band it is shown.

Is it possible to show pie chart on the Title band and if it is then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare your Pie-Chart in a separate Report and add it to the Title-Bar later on as a **Sub-Report**.

Comment: thanks for the answer but can we not directly add pie chart in Title Band? if yes then why we can not add directly add pie chart in Title Band? Can you give specific reason that will be help full for me

Comment: thanks I have created report as per your saying. as I am new in jasper so can you give me reason why we can not add pie chart directly in title band??

Comment: according to my information, the title bar can only contain static information thus being rendered before the rest of the report is processed.